# Deleting rows with cells of certain values

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub workbook()
  Dim LR As Long, i As Long
  LR = Range("E:F" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  For i = LR To 1 Step -1
  If (Range("E:F" & i).value < 400) Then rows(i).Delete
  Next i
End Sub
```

I am trying to delete rows in columns E and F on my excel worksheet that have values less than 400.

However, the Range function does not seem to work when selecting two columns at a time (without a specific range such as E1:F10).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I m not familiar with Excel but maybe that helps:   
 If (("E" & i).value < 400 and ("F"&i).value < 400 ))  Then rows(i).Delete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to delete rows that have value greater than 400 either in column "E" or "F" you should try something like :

```
Sub workbook()

  Dim LR As Long, i As Long
  LR = Range("E" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  For i = LR To 1 Step -1
      If Range("E" & i).value < 400 or Range("F" & i).value < 400 Then 
          rows(i).Delete
      End If
  Next i

End Sub
```

If you require both columns to have values greater than 400, replace `or` by `and`.

Comment: `LR = Range("E:F" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` that's bad code XD

Comment: I completely agree, I didn't even see that.

Comment: But col E and F may not have the same number of rows, in this case this is a way to get the highest without adding another if statement.

Comment: @Louis.B This is under the assumption column E and F have the same number of rows. The `EndIf` and `LR = Range("E:F" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` give me an error when running.

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I just edit my answer, `EndIf` should be `End If` and if they have the same number of rows, you can then write : `LR = Range("E" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`. It should run like that.

Comment: @Louis.B Thanks for your reply. How come column F is not included in `LR = Range("E" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` though?

Comment: @user112947, what you want to do is to count the number of rows, however you need to specify to excel in which column you want to count the rows. As long as you are sure that column F and E have the same number of rows, you could use either. If you're not sure, the best way to ensure getting all rows would be to count the number of rows in both columns separately and then take the highest.

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub workbook()

Dim LR As Long, i As Long
LR = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

For i = LR To 1 Step -1
    If Range("E" & i).Value < 400 And Range("F" & i).Value < 400 Then Rows(i).Delete
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Can I just ask what `LR = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row` does? Also is column F also included in this code?

Comment: it gets u the last element in column E

Comment: @user112947 if you are testing both rows for deletion, logic dictates that it doesn't matter which column you pick to find last row. Of course, if you picked the one that's longer, your loop is unnecessarily extended but the difference can't be that great given your chosen architecture. Also kind of amusing that you picked another answer when it was incorrect XD